# What to put in default wsdl2java implementation?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl2java

I'm trying to implement a SOAP Web Service that generates a SOAP message for managing Address Book entries. The SOAP API is from Blackboard ConnectTxt and provides a single service -"addressbook" to maintain address book entries. This service permits developers to request additions, updates and deletes to an address book by creating an appropriate SOAP message.

Using Apache CXF 2.6.1 I've generated objects from their [WSDL](http://www.txttools.co.uk/connectors/soap/addressbook/txttoolsAddressbook.wsdl) and a default impl (below)

```
@javax.jws.WebService(
                      serviceName = "TxttoolsAddressbookServiceService",
                      portName = "TxttoolsAddressbookServicePort",
                      targetNamespace = "http://www.txttools.co.uk/connectors/soap/addressbook/definitions",
                      wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/Users/me/Workspaces/work/bbtxttools/src/main/resources/wsdl/txttoolsAddressbook.wsdl",
                      endpointInterface = "uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.definitions.TxttoolsAddressbookService")
                      
public class TxttoolsAddressbookServiceImpl implements TxttoolsAddressbookService {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TxttoolsAddressbookServiceImpl.class.getName());

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.definitions.TxttoolsAddressbookService#addressbook(uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.AddressbookRequest  addressbookRequest )*
     */
    public uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.AddressbookResponse addressbook(uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.AddressbookRequest addressbookRequest) { 
        LOG.info("Executing operation addressbook");
        System.out.println(addressbookRequest);
        try {
            uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.AddressbookResponse _return = null;
            return _return;
        } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The addressbook method simply returns an empty response. I'm baffled as to what should go in here. I would have expected to code some DAOs to provide data but the method appears to do nothing. I'm obviously missing a trick somewhere. The AddressBookService is included:

```
    @WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.txttools.co.uk/connectors/soap/addressbook/definitions", name = "TxttoolsAddressbookService")
@XmlSeeAlso({uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TxttoolsAddressbookService {

    @WebResult(name = "AddressbookResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.txttools.co.uk/connectors/soap/addressbook/schemas", partName = "AddressbookResponse")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Addressbook")
    public uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.AddressbookResponse addressbook(
        @WebParam(partName = "AddressbookRequest", name = "AddressbookRequest", targetNamespace = "http://www.txttools.co.uk/connectors/soap/addressbook/schemas")
        uk.co.txttools.connectors.soap.addressbook.schemas.AddressbookRequest addressbookRequest
    );
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: Are you trying to create a service or just call a service in the Blackboard product from client code? There is a [client/consumer CXF example here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html).

Comment: Thanks for posing that question. I'd been generating code to write a service whilst I needed to consume it. Using the wsd2java goal with -client I was able to generate all the artifacts and a sample client. I then copied these artifacts to my src folder and dropped the client code into a Controller class. It now works as a GET request.